# NodeJS child process command to check for running processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, command-line-arguments, child-process

Having some difficulty getting my command to run as desired. I can't tell if I need a change in the code or in the command.

Goal:
ProgramA checks if ProgramB is running. Grep returns processes that match. Flag returns true. A connects to B. If not running, Flag returns False.

I think the issue is in my child process command to query the active processes. It checks the number of processes and returns the count. If the program is running, command returns the number (ex 4) and trueFalse returns true. If the ProgramB isn't running, command returns 0. trueFalse flag returns false.

After digging more: seems like maybe my logic in the trueFalse is bad? Im attempting to take the stdout, and string it, and then check if it's more than a number. Which seems to always return false. But I can't figure out why. Its driving my nuts. Im sure its something simple too.

Code:

```
// Variable for application process we are checking.
let query = 'ProgramB';

const programCheck = (query, trueFalse) => {
        // Using nodeJS to find the OS
        let platform = process.platform;
        // Variable to hold command to send to terminal
        let cmd = ''; 

        // Switch for the platform to distinguish which OS the user has - So we can use the
        // correct command for querying the active processes. 
        switch(platform) {
            // Windows 
            case 'win32' : cmd = `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq ${query}.exe"`;
            break;
            // Mac
            case 'darwin' : cmd = `ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep ${query}`;
            break;
            // Linux
            case 'linux' : cmd = `ps -ef | grep '${query}'`; 
            break; 
            // Default - Other
            default : console.log(`Unknown Operating System, unable to check ${query}`);
            break;
        }

        // Calling child process
        exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            trueFalse(stdout.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is going on? Is `trueFalse` a function? Why are you passing it in to `programCheck`? Is `programCheck` supposed to return `true` or `false`? How are you calling `programCheck`?

Comment: programCheck gets called when an HTML button is clicked. (Sorry, should have made that clear). The idea for trueFalse - is that it will be bool when calling the child process in exec(..). I just need a flag for the system to resolve 'Yes ProgramB is running send connect command  -or-  No ProgramB is not running, send start command'

Comment: The current code i have works perfect for Windows, but the Mac command gives me the issue.

Comment: for argument's sake. can you edit your post and add the function for `trueFalse()`

Comment: additionally, there is a very popular module which can help here. 
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node